# OSGi bundle starting problem: missing requirement

Tags: java, osgi, mqtt, osgi-bundle

Each time I try to start an OSGi bundle I get a `missing requirement` error, even though the compilation through `mvn install` is successful and all the necessary packages are exported.

When I start the bundle I always get this error:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
        Error starting bundle 124: Unable to resolve org.test.osgi-client [124](R 124.0): missing requirement [org.test.osgi-client [124](R 124.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[org.test.osgi-client [124](R 124.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
```

Any idea on how to solve this? I tried everything and it just won't start...

Comment: Do you have a suitable paho client bundle installed and resolved?

Answer (score 2):

From the message, it appears the bundle imports the package `org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3` with the version range `[1.2.0,2.0.0)` and that no other bundle exports that package having a version in the requested range. Thus the error message because the OSGi framework cannot find a suitable provider for the import package request.